# Tkinter: How to put user input into a list to access later?

Tags: python, tkinter, nonetype

When I try to access the list produced by the function stringToList, it always says TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

```
class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Many widgets defined and placed here
    def my_fx(self):
        def stringToList(input_str):
            number_list = []
            full_list = []
            if list(input_str)[-1].isnumeric:
                input_str += ","

            for item in list(input_str):
                if item.isnumeric():
                    number_list.append(item)
                if not item.isnumeric():
                    num_str = ""
                    for item in number_list:
                        num_str += item
                    if int(num_str) not in full_list:
                        try:
                            full_list.append(int(num_str))
                        except ValueError:
                            pass
                    number_list = []
            sorted_list = sorted(full_list).append(some_string)
            return sorted_list
        if True:
            sorted_list = stringToList(some_entry_widget.get())

        def do_stuff():
            from my_other_file import my_other_fx
            this_and_that = my_other_fx(sorted_list)

    # More functions defined here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = IntegratorApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

This line in my_other_fx (which is properly named in my original code) is where I get the NoneType is not subscriptable error:

```
if sorted_list[-1] == some_value:
```

I've tried reworking stringToList so it uses IntVar and StringVar instead of regular int and str, but that didn't change anything. Why is it NoneType?
Also if anyone has other critique, it's more than welcome! I'm trying to learn!

EDIT: It seems to go "nope" and turn into NoneType when I try to append a string to the list. But why??

Comment: In `sorted_list = sorted(full_list).append(some_string)`, you are assigning the result of `.append()`, NOT `sorted()` - and that is None.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
full_list.append(some_string)
sorted_list = sorted(full_list)
```